# Reloading the jqGrid after an inline edit

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to reload the jqGrid after an inline edit or tap in to an event where I can save some values using `jQuery.data()` after the save button is clicked on the pager. I have seen a lot of talk about using `$("#gridid').edit();` however my jqGrid is currently not set up to use that function and I'm not really sure how `$("#gridid').edit()` would be integrated into my current setup either.

```js
/***********************************************************
*********************jqgrid*********************************
***********************************************************/
lastSel = "";
$(function(){
  var myGrid = jQuery("#list");
  console.log(myGrid);

  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'php.scripts/customers.get.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['idcustomers','firstname', 'lastname','address1','address2','city','state','zip','phone','email','cell'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'idcustomers', index:'idcustomers', width:55}, 
      {name:'firstname', index:'firstname', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'lastname', index:'lastname', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'address1', index:'address1', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'address2', index:'address2', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'city', index:'city', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'state', index:'state', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'zip', index:'zip', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'phone', index:'phone', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'email', index:'email', width:90, editable: true}, 
      {name:'cell', index:'cell', width:90, editable: true}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[20,100,300],
    sortname: 'idcustomers',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    shrinkToFit: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Customers',
    width: 1400,
    height: 290,
    editurl: 'php.scripts/jqgrid.updaterow.php',
    ajaxGridOptions: {type:"POST"},
    onSelectRow: function(id){ 
        if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
            jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastSel); 
            lastSel=id;
            jQuery("#list").data('selid',lastSel);

            console.log(lastSel);
            console.log(jQuery("#list").data('selid'));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php.scripts/customers.setid.php",
                data: { idcustomers: jQuery("#list").data('selid') }
            }).done(function( msg ) 
            {
                console.log(msg);
            });

            jQuery('#list').data('selid', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,0));
            jQuery('#list').data('firstname', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,1));
            jQuery('#list').data('lastname', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,2));
            jQuery('#list').data('address1', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,3));
            jQuery('#list').data('address2', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,4));
            jQuery('#list').data('city', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,5));
            jQuery('#list').data('state', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,6));
            jQuery('#list').data('zip', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,7));
            jQuery('#list').data('phone', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,8));
            jQuery('#list').data('email', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,9));
            jQuery('#list').data('cell', jQuery("#list").getCell(lastSel,10));          
        } 
    }
  })
.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{ edit: false, add: true, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, {},  {})
.jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager",{})
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",{caption:"Toggle",title:"Toggle Search Toolbar", buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',
    onClickButton:function(){
        myGrid[0].toggleToolbar()
    } 
})
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",{caption:"Clear",title:"Clear Search",buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
    onClickButton:function(){
        myGrid[0].clearToolbar();
        jQuery('#list').data('selid', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('firstname', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('lastname', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('address1', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('address2', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('city', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('state', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('zip', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('phone', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('email', "");
        jQuery('#list').data('cell', "");
    } 
})
.jqGrid('filterToolbar');

/***********************************************************
*********************jqgrid*********************************
***********************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you -

```
onSelectRow : function(rowid){
            if(rowid && rowid!== lastsel){
                $("#datagrid").jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                $("#datagrid").jqGrid('editRow',rowid,true);
                lastsel = rowid;
            }
        },
```

`editrow` method triggers `jqgrid` with edited data and passes one extra parameter oper to url and all it selected row data.
In `editurl` option your url contains one parameter with oper so by using this parameter at server side, you can update your data in php in database.
There is no need to use ajax call for this.